# Base64 image on android image view

Tags: android, base64

My base64 image code is here :

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAyCAQAAAD2dTOtAAAApElEQVRIx2OYxQCHvlggw38oZBgcCrFCihQ2YIFDViH1g+cMFjhkFVI/eP5jgUNWIfWDh2iFdbMuYUCsCmcS65lRhXRRqDXrwKzDYPgci8LDUFgKMilq1h+saREBt8xig1gai1fp9llsCDcm4FS2dxYnqmfS8ClD9XUmFq9wYk/hOWjKeHBnhVK4smMgZfjyTDVY2clZ/IQzVzWwuOPHyFz/iYQAhMbywidpE3YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

This is code can work on html. e.g.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAyCAQAAAD2dTOtAAAApElEQVRIx2OYxQCHvlggw38oZBgcCrFCihQ2YIFDViH1g+cMFjhkFVI/eP5jgUNWIfWDh2iFdbMuYUCsCmcS65lRhXRRqDXrwKzDYPgci8LDUFgKMilq1h+saREBt8xig1gai1fp9llsCDcm4FS2dxYnqmfS8ClD9XUmFq9wYk/hOWjKeHBnhVK4smMgZfjyTDVY2clZ/IQzVzWwuOPHyFz/iYQAhMbywidpE3YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
```

What i wanna do is, i want to use that base64 code on android imageView. how should i do ? please.....

Answer (score 2):

1. Extract the base64 part from the string after the `,`.
2. Decode the base64 using `Base64.decode()`.
3. Decode the byte array using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`.
4. Construct a `BitmapDrawable` from the decoded `Bitmap`.
5. Use the drawable with your `ImageView`.

Comment: Now i got a error.... Because i want to add that base64 image code and imageView in my listView simpleAdapter. how should i do ?